# Django - Ajax - Uploader Model: Save file

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, file-upload

I am trying to make a django-ajax-uploader to create a model. I have created a sample but I can't understand if there is a need to use import_uploader or create a simple class to save model with file. I don't know if the AJAX actions would be disabled if I do the same.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'bft.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^bft/', include('bft.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'start$', 'bbb.views.start', name="start"),
    url(r'ajax-upload$', 'bbb.views.import_uploader', name="my_ajax_upload"),
)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from ajaxuploader.views import AjaxFileUploader

def start(request):
    csrf_token = get_token(request)
    return render_to_response('import.html',
        {'csrf_token': csrf_token}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))

import_uploader = AjaxFileUploader()
# Create your views here.
```

**import.html**

```
 <!doctype html>
        <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
            <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}ajaxuploader/js/fileuploader.js" ></script>
            <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}ajaxuploader/css/fileuploader.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/c$
            <script>
                $(function(){
                var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
                    action: "/ajax-upload",
                    element: $('#file-uploader')[0],
                    multiple: true,
                    onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                        if(responseJSON.success) {
                            alert("success!");
                        } else {
                            alert("upload failed!");
                        }
                    },
                    onAllComplete: function(uploads) {
                        // uploads is an array of maps
                        // the maps look like this: {file: FileObject, response: JSONServerResponse}
                        alert("All complete!");
                    },
                    params: {
                        'csrf_token': '{{ csrf_token }}',
                        'csrf_name': 'csrfmiddlewaretoken',
                        'csrf_xname': 'X-CSRFToken',
                    },
                });
                });
            </script>
        </head>
    <body>
        <div id="file-uploader">
            <noscript>
                <p>Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
            </noscript>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signals feature provided in the package is the answer, thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend you to create a model to store the info and the url of the file using the model FILEFIELD:

Set up your media file, wher the files will be stored
Setting.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

models.py

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
...

class UploadFile(models.Model):
      file = models.FileField(upload_to='docs/')
```

Forms.py:

```
class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    documento = forms.FileField(label='Seleccione un archivo',
                                help_text='Max Size 2mb'
                               )
    class Meta:
       model = UploadFile
```

views.py:

```
def UploadView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = UploadForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')
    else:
       form = DocuForm()
    return render_to_response("yourtemplate.html",
                              {'form':form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I display the list of documents in a table where the can click in the name of the file and download it.
if you want enable the download of the file change your urls.py in this way:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'kp.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^upload/$', 'kms.views.UploadView', name='upload'),
)+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: And how i can send other parameters with the file, if im put other filed on the form can i recive this with this plugin ajax ?

Comment: This method don't need the ajax plugin, all the work is made it int he http request from the view. In the view in this line of code 'form = UploadForm(request.POST,request.FILES)' you receive the fields and the files from the html form without using the ajax plugin

Comment: but the idea is upload as ajax for no refresh the page.

Comment: In you AJAX POST request you need to send the files and change your [url in django] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/) to accept parameters. The POST have to be sended for you ajax function and not for the django form